# Promote FILE.ReceivedFileName property in orchestrattion

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am using pass through pipeline and a filter in my orchestration so because of this file name is not promoted.

I want to promote ReceiveFileName property in my orchestration and use that in my send port.

For that I created new correlation type as file.receivedfilename

and use the correlation in my send port as initialize correlation but I am getting below error

> Failed to initialize the correlation property name: ReceivedFileName .

I don't want to achieve this is custom pipeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For clarity, FILE.ReceivedFileName has nothing to do with the Pipeline or any of it's components.  Promoted or not also does not matter.

FILE.ReceivedFileName is only set, out of the box, by the FILE or FTP Adapter.

If you are copying the Message in the Orchestration, you must also manually copy (set) FILE.ReceivedFileName on the outbound Message.

Comment: For future references: this means copying the property in the orchestration AND including it in your correlation type and set. The latter if you would like to route on this property later on.